# Allure report extension for Azure DevOps pipeline is not working

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

Getting below error when generating the Allure Test Report in Azure DevOps.

1. Installed [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivang7.allure-test-reports) to display the results in the pipeline
2. Did the setup like below

   ```
   - task: AllureGenerate@1
     condition: succeededOrFailed()
     inputs:
       resultsDir: 'allure-results'
       targetDir: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'
   ```
3. Getting error and it is not clear here

[image]